# CA2101 Warning when making extern calls

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm using the WinPcap libraries and have set up all my native method calls.  Upon building I get the [CA2101: Specify marshaling for P/Invoke string arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CA2101%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) Code Analysis warning.  My `extern` function is defined like this:

```
[DllImport("wpcap", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern int pcap_compile(IntPtr /* pcap_t* */ adaptHandle,
                                        IntPtr /*bpf_program **/fp,
                                        string /*char * */str,
                                        int optimize,
                                        uint netmask);
```

If I change the `CharSet.Ansi` to `CharSet.Unicode`, I resolve the Code Analysis warning but my function no longer works.  How can I resolve the warning and keep my code working?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This warning occurs because truncating Unicode text to an ASCII string can cause security issues.

If you cannot use Unicode strings, set `BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true` on the attribute to prevent this security issue.
For more information, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.bestfitmapping.aspx).