# Is there a way to change the color of the NonClientFrameEdges or make them invisible (particularly with WPF/.NET)?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, winapi

**Goal Summary**

I'm trying to make a WPF window with a custom window caption (so I can paint the title bar and add controls there). I've been successful in doing this with the WPF WindowChrome class, but it introduces a lot of bugs. I've been able to work around most of them by setting the WindowChrome NoneClientFrameEdges property to any value other than None, but this introduced a new bug in the process. There's an unsightly ~1px thick border where the NonClientFrameEdge property is set. You can see it in the video, but it's very faint. I want to either set the color to transparent or find a way to disable rendering it entirely. The problem is that I can't actually *remove* the NonClientFrameEdge because it's required to fix the bugs I mentioned earlier (more details below).

**Detailed explanation of the problem (as best as I can understand it)**

From what I understand, a standard window is separated into at least two parts: the client area and the non-client area. The client area is the part of the window you can easily customize, where you add your controls and other window content. The non-client area is the part of the window that includes the frame, which consists of the resize borders and the caption. Under normal conditions you can’t modify the non-client area.

The ***WindowChrome*** class in WPF provides an easy way to customize the non-client area of a WPF window. This enables you to design your own caption and place controls there like you see in modern enterprise apps such as Visual Studio and Microsoft Office. The problem is that using WindowChrome causes many bugs. Here’s a list of the ones I’ve found so far:

1. When you minimize the window from a maximized state and hover over it in the taskbar, the resulting window preview has ~8 px of empty space on the top and top-left sides. If you click it to bring it to the front, it snaps back to the proper space. Even Visual Studio and Microsoft Office have this bug. (caused by having GlassFrameThickness value of 0 set in WindowChrome class)
2. The transparent glass rectangle effect you get when hovering over the aero peek button for “peek at desktop” no longer works. You just see empty space, no outline of the app. (caused by having GlassFrameThickness value of 0 set in WindowChrome class)
3. The window is jittery when resizing from any corner other than the bottom right. I’ve read this is because resizing from these corners forces a position change of the window. (caused by having NonClientFrameEdges value of 0, at least 1 edge needs to be set to avoid this)
4. The window is distorted and blurry during the focus zoom effect when selecting a minimized window from task view. Even many enterprise apps have this problem. (Adobe Photoshop, Visual Studio, and several game launchers, to name a few). (caused either by GlassFrameThickness value of 0, NonClientFrameEdges value of None, or a combination of the two)

**Hacky solution and video before and after**

I noticed that issue 1 and 2 can be fixed by setting the GlassFrameThickness to a non-zero value. Issues 3 and 4 can be fixed by setting the NonClientFrameEdges property of the WindowChrome class to any value other than None. This video shows all of the problems listed above, along with how they look before and after changing that property: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7O28aEPygg

Note: The video ends abruptly due to my poor editing skills, but it should show all the necessary issues. You will have to look very closely at the bottom of the app in the second half of the video to see the 1px grey/white NonClientFrameEdge, but it's noticeable. This is what I'm trying to fix.

The problem is that setting NonClientFrameEdges to any value other than None literally adds a 2-3 px edge to your window, and it's visually obvious. Setting GlassFrameThickness to 1 on the same edge as the NonClientFrameEdge reduces the visibility significantly, but it's still a noticeable 1px or so eyesore. For example if NonClientFrameEdge is set to Bottom, GlassFrameThickness should be set to "0, 0, 0, 1".

**Minimal Example**
You can reproduce the problem by creating a .NET or .NET Core WPF project and adding the following code to the window's XAML view file:

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="0 0 0 1" CornerRadius="0" CaptionHeight="38" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" ResizeBorderThickness="5" NonClientFrameEdges="Bottom" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

Here's a Git Repo with a minimal project for convenience if you want it to test but don't feel like typing all the code. It includes some extra stuff like the boilerplate for the ViewModel, command firing, buttons for min/max/close, and a button to add a border for testing (makes things like the resize jitter more apparent). It also includes a hook into WndProc with Pinvoke just in case you want to experiment with the WindowsAPI: https://github.com/cjfcode/WindowProject

Comment: I think I had the same problem once and I set on the window negative margin of 8.
Margin=-8. And I played with this value according to my window's state.

Comment: Worth to mention that this problem happens with no dedicated GPUs. Tested on 3 laptops with Nvidia GPU, the bottom line is not displayed. On VMs and on one tablet with no D3D rendering, the line is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to solving this is to wire up a window hook with a handler for the `WM_NCCALCSIZE (0x83)` and `WM_NCPAINT (0x85)` messages.

`WM_NCPAINT` will allow you to remove the single pixel bottom border by calling `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`. In the code below I've wrapped that call in a method called `RemoveFrame`.

`WM_NCCALCSIZE` will allow you to change the size of the client area of the window restoring the extra space that `WindowChrome` set by using `GlassFrameThickness="0,0,0,1"` and `NonClientFrameEdges="Bottom"`.

I've wrapped up this functionality into a XAML behavior.

Here is final code that will solve your issue:

WindowChromeLoadedBehavior

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Shell;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class WindowChromeLoadedBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
    {
        private Window window;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            window = Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject);

            if (window == null) return;

            Task.Delay(5).ContinueWith(_ =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var oldWindowChrome = WindowChrome.GetWindowChrome(window);

                    if (oldWindowChrome == null) return;

                    var newWindowChrome = new WindowChrome
                    {
                        CaptionHeight = oldWindowChrome.CaptionHeight,
                        CornerRadius = oldWindowChrome.CornerRadius,
                        GlassFrameThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 1),
                        NonClientFrameEdges = NonClientFrameEdges.Bottom,
                        ResizeBorderThickness = oldWindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness,
                        UseAeroCaptionButtons = oldWindowChrome.UseAeroCaptionButtons
                    };

                    WindowChrome.SetWindowChrome(window, newWindowChrome);
                });
            });

            var hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
            HwndSource.FromHwnd(hWnd)?.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                case NativeMethods.WM_NCPAINT:
                    RemoveFrame();
                    handled = false;
                    break;

                case NativeMethods.WM_NCCALCSIZE:

                    handled = false;

                    var rcClientArea = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(RECT));
                    rcClientArea.Bottom += (int)(WindowChromeHelper.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Bottom / 2);
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(rcClientArea, lParam, false);

                    var retVal = IntPtr.Zero;
                    if (wParam == new IntPtr(1))
                    {
                        retVal = new IntPtr((int)NativeMethods.WVR.REDRAW);
                    }
                    return retVal;
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void RemoveFrame()
        {
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 && NativeMethods.IsDwmAvailable())
            {
                if (NativeMethods.DwmIsCompositionEnabled() && SystemParameters.DropShadow)
                {
                    NativeMethods.MARGINS margins;

                    margins.bottomHeight = -1;
                    margins.leftWidth = 0;
                    margins.rightWidth = 0;
                    margins.topHeight = 0;

                    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);

                    NativeMethods.DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(helper.Handle, ref margins);
                }
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
            public static RECT Empty;

            public int Width => Math.Abs(Right - Left);

            public int Height => (Bottom - Top);

            public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                Left = left;
                Top = top;
                Right = right;
                Bottom = bottom;
            }

            public RECT(RECT rcSrc)
            {
                Left = rcSrc.Left;
                Top = rcSrc.Top;
                Right = rcSrc.Right;
                Bottom = rcSrc.Bottom;
            }

            public RECT(Rectangle rectangle) : this(rectangle.Left, rectangle.Top, rectangle.Right, rectangle.Bottom)
            {
            }

            public bool IsEmpty
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Left < Right)
                    {
                        return (Top >= Bottom);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                if (this == Empty)
                {
                    return "RECT {Empty}";
                }
                return string.Concat("RECT { left : ", Left, " / top : ", Top, " / right : ", Right, " / bottom : ", Bottom, " }");
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                return ((obj is RECT) && (this == ((RECT)obj)));
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return ((Left.GetHashCode() + Top.GetHashCode()) + Right.GetHashCode()) + Bottom.GetHashCode();
            }

            public static bool operator ==(RECT rect1, RECT rect2)
            {
                return ((((rect1.Left == rect2.Left) && (rect1.Top == rect2.Top)) && (rect1.Right == rect2.Right)) && (rect1.Bottom == rect2.Bottom));
            }

            public static bool operator !=(RECT rect1, RECT rect2)
            {
                return !(rect1 == rect2);
            }

            static RECT()
            {
                Empty = new RECT();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

WindowChromeHelper

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public static class WindowChromeHelper
    {
        public static Thickness LayoutOffsetThickness => new Thickness(0d, 0d, 0d, SystemParameters.WindowResizeBorderThickness.Bottom);

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the properly adjusted window resize border thickness from system parameters.
        /// </summary>
        public static Thickness WindowResizeBorderThickness
        {
            get
            {
                var dpix = GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex.LOGPIXELSX);
                var dpiy = GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex.LOGPIXELSY);

                var dx = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.CXFRAME);
                var dy = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.CYFRAME);

                // This adjustment is needed since .NET 4.5 
                var d = GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex.SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
                dx += d;
                dy += d;

                var leftBorder = dx / dpix;
                var topBorder = dy / dpiy;

                return new Thickness(leftBorder, topBorder, leftBorder, topBorder);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

        private static float GetDpi(GetDeviceCapsIndex index)
        {
            var desktopWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
            var dc = GetDC(desktopWnd);
            float dpi;
            try
            {
                dpi = GetDeviceCaps(dc, (int)index);
            }
            finally
            {
                ReleaseDC(desktopWnd, dc);
            }
            return dpi / 96f;
        }

        private enum GetDeviceCapsIndex
        {
            LOGPIXELSX = 88,
            LOGPIXELSY = 90
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetSystemMetrics(GetSystemMetricsIndex nIndex);

        private enum GetSystemMetricsIndex
        {
            CXFRAME = 32,
            CYFRAME = 33,
            SM_CXPADDEDBORDER = 92
        }

    }
}
```

NativeMethods

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        public const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x83;
        public const int WM_NCPAINT = 0x85;

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
        public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int leftWidth;
            public int rightWidth;
            public int topHeight;
            public int bottomHeight;
        }

        private delegate int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientAreaDelegate(IntPtr hwnd, ref MARGINS margins);

        public static int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hwnd, ref MARGINS margins)
        {
            var hModule = LoadLibrary("dwmapi");

            if (hModule == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var procAddress = GetProcAddress(hModule, "DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea");

            if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var delegateForFunctionPointer = (DwmExtendFrameIntoClientAreaDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(procAddress, typeof(DwmExtendFrameIntoClientAreaDelegate));

            return delegateForFunctionPointer(hwnd, ref margins);
        }

        public static bool IsDwmAvailable()
        {
            if (LoadLibrary("dwmapi") == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        internal enum WVR
        {
            ALIGNTOP = 0x0010,
            ALIGNLEFT = 0x0020,
            ALIGNBOTTOM = 0x0040,
            ALIGNRIGHT = 0x0080,
            HREDRAW = 0x0100,
            VREDRAW = 0x0200,
            VALIDRECTS = 0x0400,
            REDRAW = HREDRAW | VREDRAW
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually tried adjusting the margins and padding on both the window and the grids before posting, but I tried it again after since you said it worked for you, but it doesn't seem to have an effect unless I'm doing something wrong. It's so frustrating because it's just a ~1px transparent border that's standing in the way of a perfect window...

Comment: It's important to note that WindowChrome will overwrite any Margin you set on the root layout panel. This is what's causing the visual glitch. You need wrap your layout with a dummy Grid that WindowChrome will set a margin on, and then one level down offset the margin it sets.

Comment: Do you have custom window style with a control template, or are you just applying WindowChrome to a normal window?

Comment: Did you happen to test that to see if it works in my project? I can't get it to work. I do have a dummy grid wrapping the main grid. If I set the margins to something ridiculous, like 300 or -300, I can see it is registering the values because a significant portion of the window turns white. However, it never effects past the nonclient edge no matter what value I use. I think that's because the nonclient edge is not owned by the window so I don't think anything we can do in XAML will fix it. Most likely will require Interop with WinAPI. I could be wrong though...

Comment: I posted a minimal example on github. It's pretty much just a standard window with WindowChrome and some boilerplate code for recreating the buttons. I do have a hook to WndProc but I have it commented out so it's not affecting anything.

Comment: I'll check out your git project.

Comment: A couple things that are important to note by the way: (1). In that project you might have to add the outer grid as I didn't add it to mine until you mentioned it. It still didn't work though. (2). The border is more noticeable if you set your windows theme to an accent color and enable accent colors on titlebar and border. (3). Just to be clear, the 1px border on the bottom isn't exactly a bug. It's literally a part of the window, basically the property NonClientFrameEdge lets you set an edge that isn't owned by the window. That's why it fixes the bugs. I want to make it invisible. Thanks!

Comment: I submitted a PR to your repo with everything working.

Comment: Hmm... I still see the same issue after merging your pull request. It's the red line at the bottom of this window (red because that's the accent color I chose in my Windows Settings to make the issue more clear). https://i.imgur.com/cIya375.png Thanks for putting in that much effort to try to help though.

Comment: Weird. I don’t see anything wrong with your screenshot.

Comment: The 1 pixel red line at the bottom is the nonclientframeedge set by WindowChrome. It's red and not blue like the rest of the border, because it's not part of the XAML border. It's the accent color set in windows. If I set NonClientFrameEdge=None it goes away of course, but then you get the jittery resizing back again. The only way to have the window resize without jitter is to have at least one NonClientFrameEdge, but then it has the unsightly 1px red border. Here's a zoomed in image that makes it more clear: https://i.imgur.com/F2ofCQ8.png

Comment: There must be some difference in settings or hardware or something else between our machines. Because everything works flawlessly on my 2 PCs here.

Comment: Try changing your accent color and check the box to show accent colors on title bars and window borders. It makes the issue more visible. It's noticeable without this setting, but since it's only 1 pixel and it's a transparent grey color, it's hard to notice without accent colors turned on. But if a user has accent colors turned on, then the color set in system will clash with the color of your XAML border as in the screenshot. I should mention this is on Windows 10. I'm not sure if earlier windows support accent colors and thus might not have this issue so easily visible.

Comment: I finally see the problem. Looking into it.

Comment: I have a final solution. I've updated the answer and also submitted a PR to your git repo.

Comment: Wow! You almost got it. This does fix the visible non-client border while retaining the smooth resizing gained from adding the non client edge, but unfortunately it removes the Aero glass frame (not sure why). As a result, the shadow is removed from the window and the Aero peek glitch where the glass rectangle doesn't show is back. Also, there's a brief flicker when the window first opens where you can see the basic default frame for a millisecond or so. I'm happy enough with it to accept it as an answer unless you know how to fix the other issues. Let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I'll take another look.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The solution should solve everything except for maybe a small flicker of a few milliseconds at load time.

Comment: In WindowChromeLoadedBehavior, I had to set handled = true in the handling of the WM_NCCALCSIZE message to get the smooth flicker-free resizing, but your solution works almost perfectly otherwise. There's only a couple of minor issues remaining. 1.) Flicker when opening the app and between maximize/restoring the app (almost every time you can see the stuff behind the app flicker briefly). 2.) Task view glitch still exists (where it zooms in weirdly, no biggie though). Other than that, it's perfect. Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Also I've found that if you change the margins from -1 to a positive value, it will remove the flicker that you get when minimizing and maximizing the window every time (but not the initial flicker) but will still fix the issue with the drop shadow. Now the only issue remaining is the initial flicker on first opening the program and the task view zoom glitch. I wish I could find a way to fix the initial flicker, the task view glitch is not really a big deal. I will keep experimenting and post back if I do.

Comment: Please update your git repo, so I can see your changes. I'd love to keep track!

Comment: I updated the repo with the fixes so far. Just need to fix the flicker on load and bind the margin since size 10 on the bottom fixes a peek glitch on maximize and size 1 on the left is best for non-maximized. I will keep it updated if I find anymore fixes.

Comment: I've found a good solution for the initial flicker on loading the window that also fixes the little bit of flicker you get near the taskbar when activating the maximized window from the taskbar preview that shows during minimized state. Hook into WndProc during the ContentRendered event instead of OnLoaded. I did notice that the DWMExtendFrameIntoClientArea function being called during NC_Paint causes an occasional brief white flicker when restoring the window from maximized state. I'll update if I find a better fix but for now it's not too noticeable.

Comment: @devpelux can you explain the edit you made? What security issue does your edit fix?

Comment: As specified here https://stackoverflow.com/q/13369883/3605220 CharSet.Ansi causes a security issue, as you can see in a warning on VisualStudio (CA2101).
Because GetProcAddress and LoadLibrary work only with CharSet.Ansi, you must add BestFitMapping = false and ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true to fix string conversion issues.

Comment: You actually don't even need DWMExtendFrameIntoClientArea to do this, the changes you made by handling NCCALCSIZE were enough.

Comment: This works great on my physical machine but I think I found a glitch when resizing on a Windows 10 VM; the left border seems to reduce e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDSKz.gif